# Algorithm to find repeating pattern in data

Tags: algorithm

I am working on parsing a large amount of CAN data is Hex format that is generated in a serial data type format and is continuously streamed. I am looking for very specific repeating patterns that are trivial to find with the eyeball method very quickly, but I am tasked with automating this process. Working in c++, but really this is a language agnostic question more dealing with the logic/algorithm to accomplish this task.

The specific pattern is an incrementing value with 8 "steps" and then it repeats 
Examples:

```
1. F0 01 A2 23 74 B5 06 07 E0 11 72 C3 D4 95 36 07 ...
2. 00 02 04 06 08 0A 0C 0E 00 02 04 06 08 0A 0C 0E ...
3. 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 00 ...
4. 00 20 40 60 80 A0 C0 E0 00 20 40 60 80 A0 C0 E0 ...


Example 1 -> low nibble,  pattern = 0123456701234567
Example 2 -> low nibble,  pattern = 02468ACE02468ACE
Example 3 -> low nibble,  pattern = 123456780123456780
Example 4 -> high nibble, pattern = 02468ACE02468ACE
```

Note that Example 3 is actually counting 9, but in this case the real count is 12345678 and the 0 is "junk" (but it is ALWAYS 0)

The unused nibble is 100% random, as example 1 shows. but the other examples i just put 0 in there to make it easier to visualize.

To confuse things just a little any of these patterns may be "stretched" - in other words, each specific value may be repeated X number of times before incrementing to the next value

Example:
    00 00 00 01 01 02 02 02 03 03 03 04 04 04 04 05 05 06 06 07 07 07

There is NEVER an out of sequence Byte - so the entire pattern above is in sequence

Also - we want to throw away "short" patterns

Bad Example for the 8 count scenario:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 00 01 02 03 04 05 00 01
```

This bad example follows all the rules properly, but it is not the required 8 counts.

We can access/process 5 bytes at a time, and new values are coming in every few milliseconds. There are several hundred bytes to process. Simple with Excel and just looking at the data, struggling to come up with a strategy / algorithm to do this in code.

The best way to visualize how the data is received is an Excel Spreadsheet - columns = memory address, row = new piece of data. I need to process for this pattern for each column.

This can be "live" (process data as it comes in) - or save several sequences of data to an array and parse it in chunks, which ever is easier

c++ code snippets, pseudo-code, or general strategy tips are appreciated
Thanks in advance for any guidance

-mleega

Comment: what you're looking for sounds very similar to compression algorithms, which find repeating sequences. If you start with one such algorithm and relax the "repeating sequence" condition (say zero the lowest bit to reduce sensor noise) to accommodate for your needs you may get close enough. These algorithms are also often suitable for streaming data

Answer (score 0):

I would just look at whether each value is greater than the previous value or not, throwing away values that are equal to the previous values. Then it sounds like you just need to detect seven increments followed by a decrement.